# What is this very short power cable called?

Tags: electrical-power

I have a couple of networking components in my rack that take giant AC adapters ("power bricks") that don't fit neatly into my rackmount PDU.

I have one "thingy" that is shown below, and I need to buy a few more. But I have no idea what I'm searching for because I don't know what the "thingy" is called.

[image: My Terrible Drawing]

Yes, this drawing is terrible. I would ask my 4-year-old to draw it for me because she's a better artist, but she's taking a nap.

Comment: You know they're putting a [tax on thingy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pmgcylAxjfY)...

Comment: Best question in awhile. lol

Comment: It's an AC adaptor, *but for your AC adaptor!*

Comment: This is currently the 'hottest' question on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: I freaking love that this got a silver badge :)

Comment: Should I be disturbed that some of the places linked to are selling pigtails for $10+ ?  (I remember years ago getting 'em at the Dayton Computerfest for $1 each ... I'd typically get a dozen or more each year)

Comment: There is no such thing as a stupid question! The answers to this one were great. I had no idea that all these options in "pigtails" existed.

Comment: This question, drawing, subsequent answers and comments fills me with great joy and I don't know why.

Comment: @Tom: I don't get it...why so?

Comment: It was a better title to begin with :)

Comment: That post-it note isn't real. So how in the _hell_ did it get crumpled? Yet more proof that graphic designers are a lazy and slapdash community. I expect my simulacra of adherent notes to be pristine! And I will accept no substitutes!

Answer (score 149, accepted):

I would just call it a "very short extension cord", and in fact a Google search for "short extension cord" turns up lots of results of exactly what you're looking for.  E.g., [these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003YFIRR6), which have a pass-through plug.

Comment: Wow. *Extension cord*. I would like to apologize to Planet Earth for the fact I required 12 people to tell me something that obvious. Score: Portman 0, ServerFault 92.

Comment: Score one for awesome, though, because this is now both your top-rated question and @larsks's top-rated answer.

Comment: Oh, ServerFault, you are a silly place.

Comment: @Portman: apology accepted ;D

Comment: +1 on the Ziotek's I've got a number of them in the rack for the goofy consumer devices I have to have in the colo.

Comment: @Portman -- the drawing more than makes up for any weakness in the actual question.  There's an artist in New York who makes very detailed sketches (in black-and-white) of US currency and then "spends" them at face value.  The Secret Service is always hounding him, calling his hand-made bills "counterfeiting", but art dealers call it art and pay thousands for examples of the work.  You could be the serverfault equivalent of that guy, posting questions like "What is this [whimsical drawing of a keyboard]?"

Comment: Hahaha, I was about to answer this question with "it's an extension cord", but you bet me to it.

Answer (score 51):

"pigtail" is a common term for these (actually any 6" to 1' power cord) in the datacenter environments I've worked in.

Comment: `pigtail` is currently most commonly used to describe SMA <> U.FL cables (needed for connecting Wi-Fi antennas to Mini PCIe cards)

Answer (score 35):

You can also get [short Y power cords](http://www.microcenter.com/single_product_results.phtml?product_id=0217389).

[image: Power Extension / Splitter "Y" Adaptor Powercord Cable]

These cables (including the single variety) are sometimes called "outlet savers".

I also love the [90° rotating plug variety](http://www.happcontrols.com/electrical_supplies/49624100.htm) for some applications. The cord goes flat against a wall.

[image: 12" Power Cord Adapter with Rotating Plug]

Comment: Just to join the party, I'll see your Y-power cord and raise you 3 more sockets - http://www.powersquid.com/powersquid-c-66.html

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Ziotek-ZT1212518-Liberator-Through-5-Pack/dp/B003YFIRR6/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1296844792&sr=8-5 I absolutely love this type of extension cord. No matter what, if you have one outlet, you can plug what you need in. Has saved me arguments many *MANY* times

Comment: @WernerCD: That is the most awesome power-related product I have ever seen.  +1 because I just bought a 5-pack.

Comment: I spent some time in the military... and there are times where there was a line of people needing power, with 2 outlets. Not a problem for me. Two of those and my laptop and gameboy is getting charged no matter how many people are hustling for the outlet.

Comment: 90 degree rotating ones? isnt the flexible wire enough to get whatever rotation you want?  sound like the anecdote about the million dollar space pen and the pencil.

Comment: @kinjal: If it's a 90 degree plug that doesn't rotate then it needs to have the cord exit at a 45 degree angle (they make them that do). Otherwise the cords get in each others' way and negates the benefit of being flat to the wall. This is needed on over-and-under wall outlets, but not usually on power strips.

Answer (score 24):

I think the official name is "Power Strip Liberator".

Google image check: http://www.google.com/images?q=power+strip+liberator

**UPDATE:**

Sorry, I think that's a product's name ([trademark](http://www.trademarkia.com/power-strip-liberator-78265771.html)), not the common name for the "thingy." But I looks like that the product is the "Coke" amongst power extension cords. :)

Comment: Liberate your power strip!! Free it from the heavy burdens of excessively large and bloated a/c adapters! Away with the tyranny of space sucking bricks! To arms! To arms!

Comment: PS: Interesting results on Google Image if you search for "liberator" alone. :)

Comment: @splattne my guess is that there should be a NSFW warning along with that suggestion!

Comment: Mmmmmm.... [Liberator](http://beeradvocate.com/beer/profile/696/15589)!

Comment: @Peter Oops, sorry! I'm already at home in weekend mode (Europe). TGIF!

Comment: @Splattne: you mean searching for liberator, thingy, or liberator + thingy?

Comment: @Bart_Silverstrim just "liberator" - I guess the search results are related to the www . liberator . com domain... **NSFW**

Answer (score 13):

It is called a pigtail extension cord. http://www.mockett.com/pt1-90.html

Comment: I usually think of "pigtail" as meaning that there are bare wires on one end. Apparently, people mean different things by it.

Comment: pigtail was the first thing I tought of as well. +1

Answer (score 9):

It's just a short extension cord, like this one from [Startech.com](http://us.startech.com/product/PAC101-12in-Power-Cord-Extension-NEMA-5-15R-to-NEMA-5-15P).

Answer (score 8):

it is called: 1ft Power Extension Cord.

I found same here:
http://www.cablewholesale.com/specs/power-cable/10w1-04201.htm

Answer (score 6):

'Very short A/C Extension' ? That's what I Googled and came up with [this](http://www.winfordeng.com/products/pwrext.php)

EDIT: 6 inch version at [Radioshack](http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2103297)

Answer (score 6):

Its called a ["Wall wart remover"](http://musicmall.com/cmp/wall_wart_removers.htm).

Comment: i never heard it before, but it's nice pigtail can be one upped.

Answer (score 5):

Um, an extension cord? (Needed 8 more characters for valid answer)

Answer (score 5):

Power strip liberators... http://www.cyberguys.com/product-listings/?categoryid=588

(No worries about your drawing... I have an art degree and probably wouldn't have done much better on a quick sketch!)

Comment: +1 for bringing art to serverfault and +1 for not being able to draw despite of this.

Comment: @Sam: -1 for leaving a comment in the wrong place. ;)

Comment: Erin is the artist who can't draw, it was directly related to him, so where to comment instead?

Comment: @Sam: Erin may be the artist who can't draw, but it was Portman who brought the art to SF.

Comment: okay, thats bad phrasing from me, but the question got a +1 too, so it isnt as bad as it sounds :)

Answer (score 4):

A short extension cord?

When in doubt, go with the obvious.

Answer (score 4):

Not really an answer, but if you need several of these things, you might want to look into the Power Squid (a semi-genericized trademark, but there's a good example [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0014XZJWG)) instead.

Answer (score 4):

Working in data centers for the past decade, I've always referred to these as Pigtails.

Comment: Pigtails to me, are the ends of fibre on a splicetray.